# Firebase multiple account per email address not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have enabled multiple accounts with the same email in firebase, it is working fine for all cases except one.

**Problem Detail:** I registered a user in firebase using Facebook, where user's Facebook account has a mobile number but no email id. later user update his email id in our app, which we updated in firebase. Now user cannot create a new user using email/password method providing same email id. ***[Please see below image for error]***

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as expected. `updateEmail` will set the top level email. This is the same email for email/password accounts. If you try to create an email/password account, it will not allow you since you already have an account with top level email set to that same email. With multiple accounts per email, when created OAuth users, the top level email is null and the email in `user.provideData` array is the only one set. Creating an email/password user will also set the top level email (in addition to adding a new `providerData` record. However, you can't have 2 users with the same top level email, phone number or same providerData email for the same provider (Facebook, Google, etc).